# Fetching system info using python

Tags: python, linux, ssh

The following piece of code does ssh do different servers and fetches the system info and display it to the user:

```
import paramiko

#list variables : ["IP_ADDR", "USERNAME", "PASSWD", "ROOT_PASSWD"]
ip_list = [
    ["192.168.11.44", "root", "****", "****"],
    ["192.168.11.8", "root", "****", "****"],
    ["192.168.11.30", "root", "****", "****"],
    ["192.168.11.6", "****", "****", "****"]
]
os_check_list = ["DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION"]
hard_disks = [
             'sda', 'sdb', 'sdc', 'sdd', 'sde', 'sdf', 'sdg',
             'sdh', 'sdi', 'sdj', 'sdk', 'sdl', 'sdm', 'sdn',
             'sdo', 'sdp', 'sdq', 'sdr', 'sds'
             ]
os = None

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

for ip in ip_list:
    ssh.connect(ip[0], username = ip[1], password = ip[2])

    print("\n \n   ************************************************************ \
           \n   IP ADDR = {}                SYSTEM INFO                           \
          \n  ******************************************************************". format(ip[0]))
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("cat /etc/*release")
    stdin.write(ip[3]+"\n")
    for line in stdout.readlines():
       if any(x in line for x in os_check_list):
           os_dist = line.split("=")
           os = os_dist[1]
           print(" Operating System is {}" .format(os))
    if not os:
           stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("cat /etc/system-release")
           for line in stdout.readlines():
               os = line
               print(" Operating System is {}" .format(os))

    os = None

    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("sudo -k udisksctl status", get_pty = True)
    stdin.write(ip[3]+"\n")
    for line in stdout.readlines():
        if any(x in line for x in hard_disks):
            print(line)
        elif "command not found" in line:
            print("udisksctl not installed on target server")

    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("sudo dmidecode -t 0 | grep -i version", get_pty = True)
    stdin.write(ip[3]+"\n")
    for line in stdout.readlines():
        if "Version" in line:
            print(line)
        elif "command not found" in line:
            print("dmidecode not installed on target server")
```

Even though this is working, I felt like I am running too many for loops for fetching the information. How to minimize these many loops?

Comment: You probably want to use ssh certificates instead of having the password in clear text in your script (you can find quite a few tutorials on how to do that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start by making your `ip_list` easier to understand. You could write a class for this, but using a `collectins.namedtuple` is a lot easier here:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Client = namedtuple("Client", "ip username passwd root_passwd")

clients = [Client("192.168.11.44", "root", "****", "****"),
           Client("192.168.11.8", "root", "****", "****"),
           Client("192.168.11.30", "root", "****", "****"),
           Client("192.168.11.6", "****", "****", "****")]
```

For the `hard_disks`, you could use the `string` module for all lowercase letters:

```
import string

HARD_DISKS = ['sd{}'.format(c) for c in string.ascii_lowercase[:19]]
```

For your repeated stuff, you could write a function:

```
def ssh_cmd(cmd, *args, root_passwd=None, **kwargs):
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd, *args, **kwargs)
    if root_passwd is not None:
        stdin.write(root_passwd + "\n")
    return stdout.readlines()
```

This makes the rest slightly nicer to read. However, I would go further and put the other stuff in dedicated functions as well, which can then be put into a `utils.py`:

```
import string
from collections import namedtuple

Client = namedtuple("Client", "ip username passwd root_passwd")

HARD_DISKS = ['sd{}'.format(c) for c in string.ascii_lowercase[:19]]

def get_os(client):
    for line in ssh_cmd("cat /etc/*release", root_passwd=client.root_passwd):
       if any(x in line for x in os_check_list):
           # check for the obvious stuff first
           return line.split("=")[1]
    for os in ssh_cmd("cat /etc/system-release"):
       return os


def print_hard_disks(client, hard_disks=HARD_DISKS):
    for line in ssh_cmd("sudo -k udisksctl status", get_pty=True, root_passwd=client.root_passwd):
        if any(hd in line for hd in hard_disks):
            print(line)
        elif "command not found" in line:
            print("udisksctl not installed on target server")


def print_dmi_version(client):
    for line in ssh_cmd("sudo dmidecode -t 0 | grep -i version", get_pty=True, root_passwd=client.root_passwd):
        if "Version" in line:
            print(line)
        elif "command not found" in line:
            print("dmidecode not installed on target server")
```

It can then be imported in your main script:

```
import paramiko

from utils import Client, get_os, print_hard_disks, print_dmi_version

BANNER = """

******************************************************************

   IP ADDR = {}                SYSTEM INFO                           

******************************************************************"""

CLIENTS = [Client("192.168.11.44", "root", "****", "****"),
           Client("192.168.11.8", "root", "****", "****"),
           Client("192.168.11.30", "root", "****", "****"),
           Client("192.168.11.6", "****", "****", "****")]


def main(clients):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    for client in clients:
        ssh.connect(client.ip, username=client.username, password=client.passwd)

        print(BANNER.format(client.ip))
        print(" Operating System is {}" .format(get_os(client)))
        print_hard_disks(client)
        print_dmi_version(client)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(CLIENTS)
```

Comment: loved the way you have modified , especially HARD_DISKS, but I didn't get what advantage we are getting when we use namedtuple in our case. It looks a normal list and namedtuple are similar.

Comment: @Raghavendra It is exactly like a normal `tuple` (so also immutable). What you gain is that `client.root_passwd` is a lot easier to understand than `ip[3]`.